# Blend for visual studio. Can't create WPF controll library project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, blend

In other computer there was Blend for visual studio 2012 and I could create wpf and silverlight projects. On my computer (also have Blend for visual studio 2012) when I want to create new project there are two options: HTML (Windows Store) and XAML (Windows Store). But there is no WPF which I need to create wpf contoll library. Why is that? Do I have some wrong version of Blend or some plug-in not istalled?

Comment: Looks like your Computer has Visual Studio Express for Windows Store Apps, not the full (Pro) version or the like.

Comment: At first I had VS Ultimate 2012. Someone told that I have to install VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop to create wpf projects so now I am going to uninstall Ultimate and install this second one and see how it goes

Comment: With VS ultimate you should be able to create any kind of projects. Visual Studio Express only supports a limited number of project types.